# Why is my CollectionViewController not showing?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, collectionview

I have a project with a CollectionViewController, I made it programmatically, I changed the background color inside the CollectionViewController but for some reason when I run the app there is no change, my screen is still black, can you help me?

here is my code:

```
The CollectionViewController class code:
//
//  NearCollectionVC.swift
//  xCodeMaps
//
//  Created by Cristea Octavian on 16/01/2020.
//  Copyright © 2020 Cristea Octavian. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

class NearCollectionVC: UICollectionViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print("-----SETTING-----")

    collectionView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Register cell classes
    self.collectionView!.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

// MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}


override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
    return 0
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell

    return cell
}

}
```

Also I should point out that all the code inside my CollectionViewController is running, I can see printed in my console "-----SETTING-----" but my background color is not changing

And the code where I setup the class

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        window = UIWindow()
           window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

           let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
           let cvc = NearCollectionVC(collectionViewLayout: layout)

           window?.rootViewController = cvc
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }
```

I looked inside my Debug View Hierarchy and seems like my CollectionViewController is not visible

[image]

Comment: Use Xcode's View Debugging feature to see whether your controller's view is off-screen or has a bad size.

Comment: you need to add your delegates and datasource. collectionView.delegate = self and collectionView.dataSource = self and implement the necessary interfaces.

Comment: @Reshad I already did that and it didn't work

Comment: The x/y offset values of 0 are fine.  I'm wondering why there are no collection-related classes in your view hierarchy.  I think your problem is that you create a new `UIWindow` instead of the one created by default.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't use storyboard and SceneDelegate.
first, you need to delete the `Main interface`
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C74JU.png)
then, you need to delete these keys in the `info.plist.`
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/injrR.png)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any cells to show, increment the number in the `noItemsInSection` function to something other than 0. Also, extend the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocol to set the height and width of the cell. Like this

```
 class NearCollectionVC: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
   //Set the height like this
   func collectionView(_: UICollectionView, layout _: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

                return CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        }
    }
     }
```